# Django Rest Framework Serializers and Views

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm confused how to implement methods in serializers and views in DRF:

I have an account model extending AbstractBaseUser.  The viewset looks like this:

```
class AccountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'username'
    queryset = Account.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return (permissions.AllowAny(), TokenHasReadWriteScope())

        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            return (permissions.AllowAny(), TokenHasReadWriteScope())

        return (permissions.IsAuthenticated(), IsAccountOwner(), TokenHasReadWriteScope())

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            Account.objects.create_user(**serializer.validated_data)

            return Response(serializer.validated_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response({
            'status': 'Bad request',
            'message': 'Account could not be created with received data.'
        }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The serializer like this:

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)
    confirm_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'username', 'created_at', 'updated_at',
                  'first_name', 'last_name', 'tagline', 'password',
                  'confirm_password',)
        read_only_fields = ('created_at', 'updated_at',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Account.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.username = validated_data.get('username', instance.username)

        instance.save()

        password = validated_data.get('password', None)
        confirm_password = validated_data.get('confirm_password', None)

        if password and confirm_password:
            instance.set_password(password)
            instance.save()

            update_session_auth_hash(self.context.get('request'), instance)

        return instance

def validate(self, data):
        if data['password'] and data['confirm_password'] and data['password'] == data['confirm_password']:
            try:
                validate_password(data['password'], user=data['username']):

                return data
            except ValidationError:
                raise serializers.ValidationError("Password is not valid.")
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Passwords do not match.")
```

On the create method for the view, it checks if the serializer is valid then saves it and returns responses depending on the outcome.  My first question is when is the serializer create() method called?  To me it seems that the method is bypassed altogether by calling create_user (a model method) in the view's create() method.  Does it get called at all?  What is the point of having it?

Second, I'm having trouble returning a status code from the update method, the instance is saved in the serializer.  Will the code inside serializer update() work if the validation fails?

Here is what I have so far:

```
def update(self, request, pk=None):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            << what goes here??? >>

            return Response(serializer.validated_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except serializers.ValidationError as e:
        return Response({
            'status': 'Bad request',
            'message': str(e)    
        }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        return Response({
            'status': 'Bad request',
            'message': 'Account could not be updated with received data.'
        }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I desperately need some clarification.  I'm unsure how to request flows through the view/serializer methods and I'm not sure how I can save the instance in the serializer and decide which response to return in the view at the same time.

EDIT:

I removed the `create` and `update` methods and fixed `get_permissions` for `AccountViewSet` and I added username validation to `validate` as you suggested.  I also updated the serializer create and update methods, here are the new versions:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    instance = super(AccountSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
    instance.set_password(validated_data['password'])
    instance.save()
    return instance

def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.username = validated_data.get('username', instance.username)

    password = validated_data.get('password', None)
    confirm_password = validated_data.get('confirm_password', None)

    if password and confirm_password:
        instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
        update_session_auth_hash(self.context.get('request'), instance)
    else:
        instance.save()

    return instance
```

My only questions are is it necessary to call `set_password` after `create`?  Does't `create` set the password for the new user?  And is it okay to have no code in the view for `create` and `update`?  Where does `serializer.save()` get called without the view code and when does the serializer `validate` run without a call to `serializer.is_valid()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**AccountViewSet**:

you do not need `.create()` and `.update()` methods, from your example - existing ones should be sufficient

`get_permissions()` - first "if" is opening your system too wide imho should be removed - you allow anyone to do `POST` - "aka" create new account, this is ok, but everything else (like `GET` or `PUT`) - should be allowed only for the account owner or (if there is a need!) registered users

**AccountSerializer**:

- API will return HTTP400 on failed validation
- make sure that `id` field is readonly, you do not want someone to overwrite existing users
- existing `create()` method can be removed, but I think your's should looks like:

  ```
  def create(self, validated_data):
      instance = super(AccountSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
      instance.set_password(validated_data['password'])
      instance.save()
      return instance
  ```
- existing `update()` method... not sure what you wanted, but:

  - first line is permitting user to change it's username, without validation e.g. username is unique, even more, you do not check at all what is in the `username` field passed from the request, it may be even empty string or None - fallback on `dictionary.get` will be called only when key is missing in the dictionary,
  - if uniqueness of `username` will be validated on the db level (unique=True in the model's field definition) - you will get strange exception instead of nice error message for the API)
  - next is validation of the passwords (again) - that was just tested in `validate` method
  - after setting user password you save instance.. second time - maybe it is worth to optimize it and have only one save?
  - if you do not allowing to update all of the fields, maybe it is a good idea to pass `update_fields` to `save()` to limit which fields are updated?
- `validation` - just add `username` validations ;)

Just to quickly understand DRF (very simplified) - `Serializers` are API's `Forms`, `ViewSets` - generic `Views`, renderers are `templates` (decide how data is displayed)

--edit--

few more items regarding viewsets, ModelViewSet consist of:

- **mixins.CreateModelMixin** - calling validate & create -> serializer.save -> serializer.create
- **mixins.RetrieveModelMixin** - "get" instance
- **mixins.UpdateModelMixin** - calling validate & update/partial update -> serializer.save -> serializer.update
- **mixins.DestroyModelMixin** - calling instance delete
- **mixins.ListModelMixin** - "get" list of instances (browse)

Comment: I editted the question to include the changes you suggested and a few more small questions about your proposed changes.  -  Doesn't set_password get called by create?  Without the view code does serializer.save() and serializer.is_valid() still get called and when?  If not when do update/create/validate get called?

Comment: One last question, should I set the id field as readonly in the Meta for the serializer?  Or somewhere else.

Comment: I've checked in the django source, set_password is not being called during create or update, but it can be called before form.save(), then setting new password will be included in the overall form.save()

Comment: when your serializer is called with form data - validate is called, then (depending on binding it to instance - create or update) - look at the ModelViewsSet sources

Comment: there are 2 ways - in meta or field definition (or redefinition for existing one) - you can use any of those

Comment: Great that makes sense.  So I never really need update or create methods for viewsets then?  I can always do the work in the serializer?

Comment: I've just added how those metods are called

Comment: That's a huge help thank you I think I am getting the hang of it.  So those mixins will call the modelset validate or the serializer validate first?

Comment: those mixins add or extend existing methods to behave as described :)

Answer (score 6):

In your `create()` method in `AccountViewSet` class, you are creating `Account` instance when serializer validation passes. Instead, you should be calling `serializer.save()`.

If you have a look at `save()` method in `BaseSerializer` class you'll see that it calls either `create()` or `update()` method,  depending on whether model instance is being created or updated. Since you are not calling `serializer.save()` in `AccountViewSet.create()` method, the `AccountSerializer.create()` method is not being called. Hope this answers your first question.

The answer to your second question too, is a missing `serializer.save()`. Replace `<< what goes here??? >>` with `serializer.save()`. This (as I explained above), will call `AccountSerializer.update()` method.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that. I wasn't calling save in create because it would create the account without hashing the password causing it to not work at all.